# Case of atypical conditional

Tags: conditionals

I wonder how this sentence sounds in the ears of a native English speaker:

**"If I had not gone there yesterday, I would not be here today"**

The classic grammar lessons do not cover this combination of tenses, but I think there is a semantic need for it, that I personally don't know how to express otherwise.

Thanks

Dragos

Comment: The "classic grammar lessons" you are talking about are designed for ESL students, and drastically oversimplify the structure of English conditionals. Native speakers are completely unaware of this classification. Your sentence is perfectly natural for English speakers.

Comment: Yes, can't comment on "classic grammar lessons" but your sentence is not atypical at all.

Comment: As @PeterShor has mentioned, those "classic grammar lessons" are far from complete descriptions of English conditional sentences. Nevertheless, your sentence is of a type that is widely noted; look at ["mixed conditionals" in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Mixed_conditional), for example.